XML list deserialization issue (No fallback setter/field defined for creator property)
I stuck with XML deserialization of a simple (I thought) structure (see below) with Java records. I'm using 2.18.0 version for Jackon. Any ideas are appreciated!
        var xml = """
        <person>
            <accesslevels>
                <accesslevel>Level1</accesslevel>
                <accesslevel>Level2</accesslevel>
            </accesslevels>
        </person>
        """.trim();
        var mapper = new XmlMapper();
        Person person = mapper.readValue(xml, Person.class);

where
public record Person(
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "accesslevels")
        List<AccessLevel> accessLevels
) {
}

and
public record AccessLevel(
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "accesslevel")
        String accessLevel
) {
}

What I'm getting is
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No fallback setter/field
 defined for creator property 'accesslevel' (of `com.example.person.AccessLevel`)
 (through reference chain: com.example.person.Person["accesslevels"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->
 com.example.person.AccessLevel["accesslevel"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.CreatorProperty._reportMissingSetter(CreatorProperty.java:358)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.CreatorProperty._verifySetter(CreatorProperty.java:341)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.CreatorProperty.deserializeAndSet(CreatorProperty.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:273)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:472)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1497)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:348)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:361)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:246)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:543)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:578)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:447)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1497)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:348)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.WrapperHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(WrapperHandlingDeserializer.java:122)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.XmlDeserializationContext.readRootValue(XmlDeserializationContext.java:104)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4917)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3860)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3828)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:18)


accesslevel is not accessLevel, correct?

I looked at the github page just now and I see that 2.17 is the latest [stable] version. I could not find any mention of 2.18 on that page. Where did you get 2.18 from?

in maven repo it's 2.18 as the latest // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.18.0'
